# Como recuperar lista de amigos do Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Pessoal estou precisando retornar a lista de amigos do facebook usando a API do facebook 4 for PHP. Consigo logar, pegar as informações da conta mas a lista so vem o seguinte resultado para mim:

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
    )

[summary] => stdClass Object
    (
        [total_count] => 124
    )

)
```

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
$friends = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/friends'))
->execute()
->getGraphObject()
->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $friends, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

E estou com as seguintes permissões:

```
$permissions = array(
'email',
'public_profile',
'user_friends'
 );
 echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl($permissions) . '">Login</a>';
```

Como devo fazer para retornar os amigos?

Comment: Seu APP já passou pelo Review do Facebook? Pois, segundo a [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2?locale=pt_BR#review), quando você requisita mais de uma dessas permissões (public_profile, email, user_friends), o APP precisa ser revisado pelo Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro vá nas suas configurações e veja se Taggable-Friends está habilitado para você (https://www.webniraj.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Taggable-Friends.png).

Isto recuperará a lista de Taggable-Friends:

```
<?php

// requer Facebook PHP SDK 4.0.x ou +

// 

// pegar taggable friends
$taggable = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/taggable_friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// output response
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $taggable, 1 ) . '</pre>';

// output total friends
echo count( $taggable['data'] );
```

Fonte: https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/

Comment: É isto mesmo. Fiz assim e deu certinho.
Obrigado

Comment: Precisando pode perguntar!